# Get strings from the richtext box

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm here to ask this question again, actually many people replied me their answers in my first question and such question was solved already. But I'm getting a new error about out of bounds exception something. Anyway, I got a new way so I got as well a new question.

How to get some strings from rich text box. Every numbers beside of the characters **Q,W,X,Y,Z** will be stored in my 5 labels. lbl1,2,3,4,5.

The old regex code is this:
but the error always point to the array element [2].

```
  public void OnAddMessage(string sMessage)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + sMessage;

            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(richTextBox1.Text))
            {
                string line;

                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] splitContents = regex.Split(line);
                    frontVal.Text = splitContents[1];
                    backVal.Text = splitContents[2];
                    leftVal.Text = splitContents[3];
                    rightVal.Text = splitContents[4];
                    tempVal.Text = splitContents[5] + "°C";

                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Post exact error message.

Comment: What is the values of `richTextBox1.Text` & `sMessage`? what regex string is?

Comment: if you are getting an out of bounds exception and it is pointing to index 2 then you only have 1 item in the array.....ensure there are more items in the array before you try to get a value from them!

Comment: hello guys. Thank you so much for replying and sorry for not posting the exact error. I'm certain that the error always pointing in [2]. here is the regex

    private Regex regex = new Regex("[QWXYZ]");

I don't know why regex.Split() is only returning two strings, because the richtext box was outputting the complete string. like Q0.01W0.02X1.23Y5.25Z38.19Q0.02W0.32...... and so on.
Anyway, can you provide me sample piece of code (like the one I have posted) on extracting the values beside the QWXYZ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might help to reproduce and solve the problem you asked.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("[QWXYZ]");
    string lines =              "Q0.01W0.02X1.23Y5.25Z38.19" 
        + Environment.NewLine + "Q0.02W0.32X1.24Y5.22Z32.19";
    
    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(lines))
    {
        string line = "";
        int lineCount = 0;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            lineCount++;
            Console.WriteLine("Line " + lineCount.ToString());
            string[] splitContents = regex.Split(line).Where(s => s != String.Empty).ToArray();
            for(int i = 0; i < splitContents.Length; i++){
                Console.WriteLine(splitContents[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
```